# How to attach visual state to a dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf

MainWindow contains an ItemsControl that displays data from the list collection. The Name and ControlState properties are attached to the Text and VisualState dependency properties. VisualStateManager.GoToState() always returns false. How to attach a visual state to a dependency property so that the change of visual states is performed?

Сode:

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfFW.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfFW"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
    Title="MainWindowFWTest" Height="100" Width="300">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControl1  Text="{Binding Name}" VisualState="{Binding ControlState}"
                                 Width="200" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="2"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        list = new ObservableCollection<ControlData>() {
            new ControlData() { Name = "Control 1", ControlState = 0 },
        new ControlData() { Name = "Control 2", ControlState = 1 }};
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ControlData> list { get; set; }
}

public class ControlData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name;
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            SetProperty(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    private int _ControlState;
    public int ControlState
    {
        get => _ControlState;
        set
        {
            _ControlState = value;
            SetProperty(nameof(ControlState));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void SetProperty(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl1**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfFW.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfFW"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
            <VisualState x:Name="State1">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:2" Storyboard.TargetName="State1Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:3" Storyboard.TargetName="State2Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="State2">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:00:3" Storyboard.TargetName="State1Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:00:2" Storyboard.TargetName="State2Panel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border Name="State2Panel" Background="Green" Opacity="0"/>
    <Border Name="State1Panel" Background="Red" Opacity="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UserControl1, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string VisualState
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(VisualStateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VisualState", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(VisualStateChanged)));

    public static void VisualStateChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            string state = e.NewValue.ToString();
            var control = o as FrameworkElement;
            bool b = VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "state" + state, true);
        }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made several mistakes. First, the VisualStateGroup is defined in `Grid` rather than `UserControl` itself. In such case, you need to specify the `Grid` when calling a VisualStateManager method. Second, the VisualState name is case-sensitive. Third, in this case, VisualStateManager.GoToElementState method is appropriate as described in [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotostate#remarks).

In sum, if you name the `Grid` as "LayoutRoot", your VisualStateChanged method will be like the following:

```
public static void VisualStateChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        string state = e.NewValue.ToString();
        var control = o as UserControl1;
        bool b = VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(control.LayoutRoot, "State" + state, true);
    }
}
```